# Puppeteer JS page.eval won't trigger within MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, mutation-observers

Currently, I'm trying to print to console a player's bet size whenever a new bet is made on pokernow.

My code is able to scrape the players in a lobby and pull their current bet amount, when the code first runs. However, I'm trying to recognize whenever a player makes a new bet and print it to console. With the MutationObserver, I can recognize when a specific player div tag changes but I'm not able to re-evaluate that div tag to scrape their current bet.

How can I run a page eval within the MutationObserver?

My code executes this line "printMe(playerNumber + "yum");" , but doesn't hit the next printMe statement.

If I reverse the order and do page.eval then printMe(newStuff) first, the printMe(playerNumber + "yum") never prints to console.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const playerMap = {};

async function run() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    defaultViewport: false,
    headless: true,
    //saves cookies for saving captcha
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://www.pokernow.club/games/pgl4O2TEDE9Tge9k2ltFDj7Fa");

  await page.exposeFunction("printMe", (lul) => console.log(lul));

  await page.exposeFunction("getPlayerNumber", (playerTagClassName) => {
    console.log(`playerTagClassName is ${playerTagClassName}`);
    const classNameTokens = playerTagClassName.split(" ");
    return Promise.resolve(classNameTokens[1]);
  });

  await page.evaluate(async () => {
    const playerTags = document.querySelectorAll(".seats .table-player");

    for (const playerTag of playerTags) {
      if (!playerTag.className.includes("table-player-seat")) {
        const playerNumber = await getPlayerNumber(playerTag.className);

        const observer = new MutationObserver(async (mutations) => {
          for (const mutation of mutations) {
            if (mutation.type == "childList" || mutation.type == "subtree") {

              printMe(playerNumber + "yum");

              const newStuff = await page.evaluate(() => {
                return Promise.resolve("test");
              });

              printMe(newStuff);
            }
          }
        });

        observer.observe(playerTag, { childList: true, subtree: true });
      }
    }
  });
}

run();
```

I've tried calling page eval within an exposedFunction similar to how printMe functions, but that also didn't work.

Comment: `page` is a node thing. Puppeteer doesn't run in the browser, it automates the browser from a totally separate process. Anything in an `eval` block has to be 100% browser code, so no Puppeteer calls are allowed there. Puppeteer provides a convenient abstraction called `waitForFunction` so you don't typically need to bother with rolling your own `MutationObserver`.